# Catchable fatal error : Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress

> This is the error I am receiving : 
>   Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /home/iliaktida/public_html/wp-content/themes/iliaktida/includes/_wp_utils.php
>   on line 1507
>   Below is the function that falls under the error lines.

```
    // Get all post's categories
    $post_categories_list = array();
    $post_categories_ids = array();
    $post_categories_slugs = array();
    $post_categories_links = '';
    $post_root_category = '';
    if ($opt['categories_list']) {
        $post_categories_list = getCategoriesByPostId($post_id);
        $ex_cats = explode(',', get_theme_option('exclude_cats'));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($post_categories_list); $i++) {
            if (in_array($post_categories_list[$i]['term_id'], $ex_cats)) continue;
            if ($post_root_category=='') {
                if (get_theme_option('close_category')=='parental') {
                    $parent_cat = getParentCategory($post_categories_list[$i]['term_id'], $opt['parent_cat_id']);
                    if ($parent_cat) {
                        $post_root_category = $parent_cat['name'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $post_root_category = $post_categories_list[$i]['name'];
                }
            }
            $post_categories_ids[] = $post_categories_list[$i]['term_id'];
            $post_categories_slugs[] = $post_categories_list[$i]['slug'];
            $post_categories_links .= '<a class="cat_link" href="' . $post_categories_list[$i]['link'] . '">'
                . $post_categories_list[$i]['name'] 
                . ($i < count($post_categories_list)-1 ? ',' : '')
                . '</a> ';
        }
        if ($post_root_category=='' && count($post_categories_list)>0) {
            $post_root_category = $post_categories_list[0]['name'];
        }
    }
```

The line getting error(1507) is as below :

```
$post_categories_links .= '<a class="cat_link" href="' . $post_categories_list[$i]['link'] . '">'
                . $post_categories_list[$i]['name'] 
                . ($i < count($post_categories_list)-1 ? ',' : '')
                . '</a> ';
```

Any hints what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to get this solved my self after not receiving any answers for a day.

I added this code above the error line and changed the code as below :

```
if(is_wp_error($post_categories_list[$i])) {
    continue;
    $link = get_term_link($post_categories_list[$i]);
    //echo $link;
    $post_categories_links .= '<a class="cat_link" href="' . $link . '">'
        . $post_categories_list[$i]['name'] 
        . ($i < count($post_categories_list)-1 ? ',' : '')
        . '</a> ';          
}
```

This worked for me. :)